# How to change the color in colormap in surf plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, colormap

I have the following code and I have plotted a 3D plot for the stft with respect to time, frequency and amplitude. How do I change the black color seen in the plot to white? I do not understand how to change the black color to white in colormap option

```
[ss,ff,tt,pp]= spectrogram(x_dc,128*2,60,128*2,Fs);
figure,surf(tt,ff,abs(ss))
```

[Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ614.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
figure,surf(tt,ff,abs(ss), 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

That 'black colour' you see are probably the borders of each cell. Don't show them using the `'EdgeColor', 'none'` name-value pair.